# tmux: how to toggle "on" and "off" options with the same key

Tags: tmux

This is a bit of my tmux.conf

```
cat tmux.conf
...
bind a set-window-option synchronize-panes on
bind b set-window-option synchronize-panes off
```

As you can see, sync and unsync options for panes are bound to two different keys. Is it possible to toggle sync/unsync with the same key?

Comment: Tmux does not enable this by default. It can be done by writing a script, but it's not trivial.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify "on" or "off", the option will get toggled. The following would suffice:

```
bind-key a set-window-option synchronize-panes\; display-message "synchronize-panes is now #{?pane_synchronized,on,off}"
```

Comment: Very useful, I modified this answer to show the state with `display-message`. Further info variable substitution and conditionals can be found under the FORMATS section of `man tmux`, and just below that it lists the variables that are available, which `pane_synchronization` is the one we want. This is very helpful for those who use https://github.com/davidscholberg/tmux-cluster.

Comment: *`pane_synchronized` (the code was right but my comment was incorrect and it is too late to edit it)

Comment: Here is a link to a man page with the FORMATS section: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS . For whatever reason, the first 2 man pages of tmux that I looked at didn't HAVE a formats section! Lame! I had to use the query `man tmux "FORMATS"`, with the quotation marks around FORMAT, to search for it explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't bethissed to scroll in two panes at the same time since it's only for sending keystrokes into the panes, not imulatenously do tmux commands targetted at them.

Answer (score 5):

don't attach on or off. it's toggle

`bind-key a set-window-option synchronize-panes`

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible with a combination of `run-shell` and `tmux show-option`, something like (tested in tmux 2.3):

```
bind a run-shell "if [[ `tmux show-options -w | grep 'synchronize-panes.*on'` ]]; then toggle=off; else export toggle=on; fi; tmux display-message \"sync panes tmux: \$toggle\"; tmux set-option -w synchronize-panes \$toggle &> /dev/null"
```

(this is a variation of a mouse-mode toggle found on the [TMux user mailing list](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/month=20110901))

Comment: Thanks for the link for mouse-mode toggle. Just looking for this. Here's the mouse toggle I settled with:

  bind m run-shell "if [[ `tmux showw | grep mode-mouse.*on` ]]; then toggle=off; else export toggle=on; fi; tmux display-message \"Mouse: \$toggle\"; tmux setw mode-mouse \$toggle &> /dev/null; for cmd in mouse-select-pane mouse-resize-pane mouse-select-window; do tmux set -g \$cmd \$toggle &> /dev/null; done;"

Comment: Ojp's answer is simpler, but it didn't work for me for the mode-mouse setting in tmux 1.8, perhaps because the setting can take a value other than on/off (on/off/copy-mode). The method here does work for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of **toggling** the mouse on and off with ^M:

```
bind-key c-M  set-option -g mouse \; display-message 'Mouse #{?mouse,on,off}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution based on the answer by Frank Schmitt:

```
!/usr/bin/bash

USAGE="USAGE: $0 OPTION_NAME ON_STATE OFF_STATE"

OPTION_NAME=$1
ON_STATE=$2
OFF_STATE=$3

if [[ "$#" != 3 ]]; then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi

if [[ `tmux show-option -w | grep "$OPTION_NAME $ON_STATE"` ]]; then
  OPTION_VALUE=$OFF_STATE
else
  OPTION_VALUE=$ON_STATE
fi

tmux display-message "monitor activity: $OPTION_NAME $OPTION_VALUE"
tmux set-option -w $OPTION_NAME $OPTION_VALUE > /dev/null
```

The script takes the name of the option, the on value and the off value. Not very well tested but works for simple cases like:

```
PATH_TO_SCRIPT_ABOVE monitor-activity on off
```

In your .tmux.conf:

```
bind-key <SOME_KEY> run-shell "tmux_toggle_option monitor-activity on off"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is different set of answers in this page, and it's confusing.

- Either we are calling a [tmux built-in variable](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#Variable) that are toggling on/off, then we can use them directly.
- In fact, any other value that we may set in the tmux.conf that has the on/off behavior, can be used for toggle in one call, as shown in other answers in this page.

However, there is many other values types, and for them we have to use a separate script. We could then call this script from a shortcut.

This example shows how to toggle the status bar on top/bottom:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUSPOS=$(tmux display -p '#{status-position}')

if [ $STATUSPOS == 'top' ];then
  tmux set -g status-position 'bottom'
else
  tmux set -g status-position 'top'
fi
```

We have to test for the values ourselves to get back the toggling behaviour.